# Properties of Consumer Preferences - Monotonicity

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, preferences

Was reviewing topics and I came across this question. I am confused because there is no reference to strict or weak monotonicity in this case. I first thought that monotonicity is violated b/c an increase in any good does not seem to lead to a higher preference, but I'm straying away from that idea.

Looking for an answer with an explanation to help me study for an upcoming exam:

**Joe can choose among (only) 4 bundles of goods, A-D. Each
bundle contains the following quantities of good X (first #) and of good Y (second #):

A = (10, 1), B = (10, 0), C = (5, 5), D = (0, 10).

He prefers A to B, B to C, C to D, A to C, A to D, and B to D.

c. Do his preferences violate monotonicity (that more is preferred to less)? Explain briefly.

d. For the above bundles A-D, suppose instead that he prefers B to A, but all the other
preference orderings are unchanged. Do his new preferences satisfy (i) transitivity, and
(ii) monotonicity? Explain each briefly.**

Comment: Hi! What exactly are you looking for from an answer? Is someone supposed to guess whether the writer of the question was thinking of *strong* or *weak* monotonicity?

Comment: If you are in a similar situation in an exam just write out your answer w.r.t. both types of monotonicity.

Comment: "*I first thought that monotonicity is violated b/c an increase in any good does not seem to lead to a higher preference, but I'm straying away from that idea.*" What about "*He prefers A to B*"?